# How to stop latex from moving pictures to other than intended position in the pdf file?

Tags: graphics, positioning, diagrams

This is my sample code:
Is there any comand I could write to force latex to let the pictures stay on the intended position?

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 
    pointlessnumbers, 
    %draft,
    parskip=half,
    automark
        ]{scrartcl}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} 

\usepackage[a4paper, left=2.2cm, right=2.2cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm,]{geometry}
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\clearscrheadfoot
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}


\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx,color}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm, amsfonts} 
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[decimalsymbol=comma]{siunitx} 


\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor} 
\usepackage[centerlast,small,sc]{caption}
\usepackage{here}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{titling}

\usepackage{subfigure}


\usepackage{hyperref}


    \renewcommand{\i}{\mathrm{i}}
    \newcommand{\e}{\mathrm{e}}
    \newcommand{\diff}{\mathrm{d}}
    \newcommand{\figref}[1]{Abb. \ref{#1}} 

    \newcommand{\ImNew}{\operatorname{Im}}
    \newcommand{\ReNew}{\operatorname{Re}}
    
    \newcommand{\xdot}{\! \, \cdot \! \,}
    \newcommand{\funof}[1]{{\color{gray}(#1)}}
    
%Titelseite
\title{hh}
\author{hh}
\date{Versuchsdurchführung: 08.10.2020}

%Dokument
\begin{document}
\setcounter{page}{0}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty} % Keine Seitenzahl auf Titelseite
\ofoot{\upshape\thepage}

\clearpage
%Inhaltsverzeichnis
%\thispagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents

\clearpage
%Hauptdokument
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\ihead{\upshape\scriptsize \leftmark}
\ohead{\upshape\scriptsize \thetitle}
%\ifoot{\upshape \scriptsize}
\ofoot{\upshape\thepage}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{../SC Bilder/sc1.png}
\caption{Veranschaulichung der Erzeugung von linear polarisierten Licht und zirkular polarisiertem Licht} 
\label{fig:0}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Comment: TL;DR: `figure` (and `table`) are float environments, meaning that TeX is allowed to move them to where it thinks best.  If you don't want that moving, then don't use `figure`.  If you still want a caption, get that some other way.

Comment: If you want captions on non-floating environments, look at https://ctan.org/pkg/capt-of or https://ctan.org/pkg/caption

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use placement specifier so that Latex understands not to find the "optimum" position for the float.

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{../SC Bilder/sc1.png}
\caption{Veranschaulichung der Erzeugung von linear polarisierten Licht und zirkular polarisiertem Licht} 
\label{fig:0}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Without you I could have never submitted the paper!!!